# C# Background Worker UI Update from class

Tags: c#, user-interface, progress-bar, backgroundworker

i come from a java environment and just recently started to learn C#.

**(Please scroll a t the end of the question to see solution)**

I'm Trying to use a background Worker to fetch some data from a Webservice do some calculations and update the UI, but i cant seem to make it report the progress back

So i Have my Form1.cc which contains the MainForm class that represents my UI Form (contains 2 date pickers , 1 progress bar and a button).

on the button i have binded the following click handler:

```
private void runReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

 private void runReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("button pressed\n datefrom "+dateFrom.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd" ));
            AdStage data=new AdStage(dateFrom.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), dateTo.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
            //this.progressLabel.Text = "Fetching Data From Adstage";       
            //data.setUIProgressItems(progressLabel, this.progressBar);
            data.setUI(this);
            data.startWorker();
        }
```

On the Adstage.cs i have all my logic to handle staff on the background.

```
 /*constructor*/
        public AdStage(String dateFrom, String dateTo)
        {
            //set the dates 
            setDates(dateFrom, dateTo);

        }
        public void startWorker()
        {
            doBg();//start bg worker...
        }

        public void setUI(MainForm ui)
        {
            this.ui = ui;
        }

 private void setDates(String dateFrom, String dateTo)
        {
            if (dateFrom.Equals(dateTo))
            {
                this.dateTo = this.dateTo = dateFrom;
            }
            else
            {
                this.dateFrom = dateFrom;
                this.dateTo = dateTo;
            }
        }

private void doRequest(String offset,String url= null,BackgroundWorker worker=null,int p=0)
    {
    //all of the logic that gets data from the web serivces is here
}



private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("worker_runWorkerCompleted"));
            //update ui once the job has finished..
            MessageBox.Show("Data Fetched! Total Campaigns: "+this.campaigns.Count());
            //this.ui.updateProgress("Fetched " + this.campaigns.Count() + " campaigns",100);
            //this.ui.progressLabel.Text = "Fetched "+this.campaigns.Count()+" campaigns";


        }

        public void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Testing worker_ProgressChanged: "+e.ProgressPercentage.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show("Progress: " + this.campaigns.Count());
            this.ui.progressLabel.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();
        }
```

And this is my DoWork function

```
 private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
            {   
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("worker_doWork"));
                //do all major background work here..   
                BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
                worker.ReportProgress(1);
                doRequest(offset,null,worker);
                (worker as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(99, null);
                //worker.ReportProgress(100);
            }
```

So even id if use the report progress inside of the doRequest() function its like the  worker_ProgressChanged is never called. The worker goes on, fetches all pages from the web service, and only reports back when finished. 
The worker_ProgressChanged event never occurs..

EDIT: clarifying my code to help people understand what i am doing :)

I have the worker be created in a method called doBG();

```
private void doBg()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("BG WORKER STARTED"));
            this.worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
            this.worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
            this.worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
```

When the buttn runReport is clicked, i have an instance of the class Adstage be created. ( `AdStage data=new AdStage(dateFrom.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), dateTo.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));`)

Then on that instance i set the ui (this is just so i can access the mainForm members from the Adstage class)

and then i start the background worker from the mainFOrm by making a call to data.startWorker(); (which basically just call the doBG() functions of the Adstage class). This is because i have set the doBG() to be private on the Adstage class.

**EDIT 2:** 
Adding `this.worker.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;` inside of the doBg() function, seems to do the trick , thank you Dirk for pointing that out and thank you Machine Learning for the good tips :)

Also to anyone having same issues, you can also update the ui using delegates. 
Check this answer here to get an idea how to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3303276/514657  (it really helped me understand how to work with delegates)

Comment: I don't see where you intialize the `BackgroundWorker`, but have you set its property [`WorkerReportsProgress`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.workerreportsprogress.aspx) to `true`?

Comment: i initilise it inside a private function called doBG(); in the Adstage class :)

Comment: And do you ever add the `worker_ProgressChanged` method to the `worker.ProgressChanged` event?

Comment: actually i had no idea you have to set it up (i thought it could find it out by naming convention or something.. how dumb of me :P) 

Thanks i think now it should be working. :D

Answer (score 0):

*Don't* pass the UI form to the Background worker, but write the ProgressChanged in the UI form.

So, again, ProgressChanged (as well as RunWorkerCompleted)  must not be a method of the worker because you can't update the UI from another thread.

Comment: I basically pass the UI to the Adstage Class. That class contains all the logic + the function that will initialise a background worker. 

Are you saying i should create a public function in the Adstage class that gets the worker object, and use that object inside the mainForm class ?

Comment: No I'm saying that the Adstage Class (is it your Background worker?) should contain only the DoWork method that is what you need to execute in background while the progress changed and the completed methods are typically to show the results in the UI and must be in UI class.

Comment: So it's easier if you initialize the method in the UI (unless you want to play with delegates) because you have to set ProgressChanged and RunWorkerCompleted with UI methods

Comment: thanks for the tips :) i'm gonna try it out on later. Basically the Adstage class is a normal class and does not extend the background worker, so it should be ( i think) safe to call ui functions to update staff inside of it. 

I know its probably best though to just have the ui update only in the form class, but for now i'm looking for a quick way around.  Still appreciate the best practice tips though :) thanks :)