# writing to/updating a TextBox in "real time" on a networked form C#

Tags: c#, textbox, network-programming

I have a windows form in visual studio 10 that connects to a python server program and receives a string of data repeatedly from the server. it then writes this string to a textbox. currently for testing purposes the server sends this string 10 times and then turns off. what i want the client to do is after it receives each string it writes it to the text box immediately but currently it waits until the server has finished and then writes the last string. the client code for this is as follows:

```
while (TestConnection(client))
                {
                   char tt = ' ';
                   try{
                       tt = Convert.ToChar(clientStreamReader.Read());
                       if (count < 17)
                       {
                           message = tt.ToString();
                           m += message;
                           count += 1;
                       }
                       else if (count >= 17)
                       {
                           textBox2.Text = m + "\r\n";
                           m = "";
                           count = 0;
                       }
                   }catch(OverflowException){
                            m += "";
                   }                
                }
```

how can I change this to write each string as they are received?

(TestConnection is a custom bool that indicates weather the connection is good)
EDIT:
(loop is inside button click event)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302915/c-sharp-update-and-append-textbox-value-using-backgroundworker-process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write an background Worker process, which always checks in a loop if there is a new string wich can be written to your textbox.
Check out this link: [example on CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/841751/multithreading-using-a-background-worker-csharp)

Comment: does that work with a loop started on a button click?

Comment: @drako234  the loop needs to be in the background worker process

Comment: @drako234 but you can start your background worker with the button click event